# Using CPU clock as an increment timer?

Tags: vb.net, timer, cpu

Has anyone ever tried using the CPU clock frequency as an incremental timer?  Maybe this is pretty common?  I have a project where I need to record data at 1khz - 10khz rates.  I was trying to use the timer class in VB.net set to increment at 1ms but testing showed that it was not fast enough as it is set to the system clock and the system's clock resolution is only around 15mS on a Windows 7 system.

Comment: You are setting very unrealistic goals.  You can record, barely, at 1 KHz by pinvoking timeBeginPeriod() and timeSetEvent().  But that's as fast as you can go from a user mode program.  Don't use Stopwatch, you'll lose a lot of data.

Comment: What are you recording? Often time the hardware that capture the data stores it in a buffer. You can then loop less frequently and read out of that buffer. An other option is to capture the delta in time between each call and simulate.

Comment: Lotus, yes, it looks like that is the way that I'm going to have to do it - load data into an array and then append the data in that array to the data file every 5 seconds or whatever.  I believe I was overthinking this a bit too much and writing a program to where my Visual Studio program was doing all of the work.  Well, at least I know so far from the responses that I can't use a CPU clock as an incremental timer.  Thanks